# Failed to start a TensorBoard session in vscode due to the following error:

Tags: tensorboard

To launch tensorboard in vscode, I did the following steps:

1. select a python interpreter path
2. choose `Python:Launch TensorBoard`

and then I get this error:

```
We failed to start a TensorBoard session due to the following error: Command failed: conda activate ldl && echo 'e8b39361-0157-4923-80e1-22d70d46dee6' && python /home/cxy/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.18.2/pythonFiles/printEnvVariables.py

CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
If your shell is Bash or a Bourne variant, enable conda for the current user with

    $ echo ". /home/cxy/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" >> ~/.bashrc

or, for all users, enable conda with

    $ sudo ln -s /home/cxy/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh /etc/profile.d/conda.sh

The options above will permanently enable the 'conda' command, but they do NOT
put conda's base (root) environment on PATH.  To do so, run

    $ conda activate

in your terminal, or to put the base environment on PATH permanently, run

    $ echo "conda activate" >> ~/.bashrc

Previous to conda 4.4, the recommended way to activate conda was to modify PATH in
your ~/.bashrc file.  You should manually remove the line that looks like

    export PATH="/home/cxy/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"

^^^ The above line should NO LONGER be in your ~/.bashrc file! ^^^
```

I have tried the suggested command, which is
`echo ". /home/cxy/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" >> ~/.bashrc`
but it doesn't work, I still get the same error.

How can I solve this problem? Is there any suggestion? thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved this problem!!!

Basically, it is caused by the latest version of Python and Pylance extension in vscode, all we have to do is simply downgrade the two extensiona and make sure vscode won't update them automatically.

So, do the following:

1. Downgrade `Python extension` and `Pylance extension` to eariler version, like **v2021.10.xx** and **v2021.10.0** respectively.
2. Close the extension `auto update` in vscode, to ensure the downgradion in step1 works after restarting vscode.

   Specifically, open`Settings` and search for the keyword `update`, do the following:

   2.1. beneath the `Update: Mode`,select `None` instead of `default`

   2.2. beneath the `Extensions: Auto Update`, select `None` instead of `All extensions`

---

After I did the above steps, the problem just disappeared. I can then  launch tensorboard by `shift+cmd+P` and select `Python:Launch TensorBoard`.

Answer (score 0):

I can make it run with the latest versions of the extensions.

First, run your code within the appropriate virtual environment (or using the appropriate python interpreter).

Second, while/after running, change the python interpreter to python 3.6.9 (usually recommended in vscode under linux).

Third, launch your tensorboard, select your log dir, and it will work normally.